# How to trigger a form_for submit (rails) from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery Bootstrap Star Rating (http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating). I am stuck trying to pass value it gets to Rails form_for. I do not know how to submit the form with value obtained from script.

```
<%= form_for @book.reader_books.build, id: "my-form", :html=> {:id => 'my-form'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: @book.id, :id=>"rating_field" %>     
      <div class="col-md-6 ratings">
        <div align="center"><%= @book.rating_average.to_i %></div>
        <input id="input-id" name="input-id">
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <strong>Your rate:</strong>
    <%= @book.reader_books.find_by!(reader: current_reader).rating %>
```

Script that should trigger form submission:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#input-id').rating().on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
        console.log(value);
        $("#rating_field").val(value);
        $("#my-form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

`console.log(value);` - Just checking if the data is entered.
`$("#rating_field").val(value);` - Assigning `value` to the field.
`$("#my-form").submit();` - triggering a submit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

doing `$("#my-form").submit();` **will NOT submit the form remotely. Instead a full refresh will occur**

```
$("#my-form").trigger('submit.rails');
```

is the rails way of doing it.

**EDIT**

rails-ujs has a convenient wrapper for this

```
form = document.querySelector('form');
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Rails is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#input-id').rating().on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
    // traversing up the DOM is faster and avoids hardcoding an ID.
    var $form = $(event.target).parents('form');
    // You can get inputs by name from a form element without querying the DOM.
    $form[0]["reader_book[book_id]"].value = value;
    $form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using the `click()` function ***on the submit button***, not on the form.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click();
```

or

```
$('#submit-button').click();
```